# CodeIgniter getMethod() Deprecated and Submit Button not functioning

Tags: codeigniter, email, form-submit, submit-button, getmethod

I practice my CodeIgnitor right now and I'm new to them still. I am doing the inquiry form and wanted to make sure that it checks the form is correctly verified. After clicking on the submit button, It will send the form to a corresponding email.

*but I'm having issues saying **getMethod() is deprecated** and my **submit button is not responding too**.*

In fact, I don't grasp what deprecated means are, and are there anybody who can assist me clarify this part and provides any other approach before using getMethod().

Can you guys check what I did wrong with the submit button too? If you have a better approach to validate the form and send the email to the corresponding that somewhat cleaner. It's also wonderful.

This is my code:-

**config/Controller/Contact Controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    // CONTACT PAGE
    public function contact()
    {
        //Library
        helper(['form']);

        //Contact Data Initiate
        $contact_data = [];
        $data = [
            'meta_title' => 'Contact | MFD',
        ];
        
        //Check request if it is post
        if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){

            // Setting Form Rules
            $settings_rule = [
                'email' => [
                    'name' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
                    'email' => 'required|valid_email',
                    'subject' => 'required',
                ],
                'msg' => 'required',
            ];

            if($this->validate($settings_rule)){
                //Validation true send message successfully sent and return back to the same page
                return view('page_templates/contact', $data);

            }else {
                // Will provide check list of error of the one we create 
                $contact_data['validation'] = $this->validator;
            }
        }

        return view('page_templates/contact', $data);
    }
```

**views/page_templates/contact.php**

```
               <div class="col-lg-8 mt-5 mt-lg-0">

                    <?php if(isset($validation)) : ?>
                        <div class="error-message">
                            <?= $validation->listErrors(); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif ?>

                    <form method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" 
                                    value="<?= set_value('name'); ?>" placeholder="Your Name">       
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" 
                                    value="<?= set_value('email'); ?>" placeholder="Your Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" 
                                value="<?= set_value('subject'); ?>" placeholder="Subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message"><?= set_value('msg'); ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div class="my-3">
                            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                        </div> -->

                        <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
                        <div class="text-left button">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
```

**Really appreciate it if anyone that can help me with this. Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the exact deprecation message that you are getting? And which version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Deprecation just means that the interface will be removed in future revisions.

But I just looked at the source and documentation and the method doesn't appear to be deprecated. The optional parameter `$upper` is deprecated though.

So you would not want to use `$this->request->getMethod(TRUE | FALSE)` since that wont be supported in the future. But `$this->request->getMethod()` should be fine.

As for your button problem... You didn't provide enough information.

For the client rendered button to respond to a click event you will need to add a listener. I am guessing you have not. It goes something like this.

```
<script>
   let button = document.querySelector(".button button");
   button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
       // Do your work here...
   });
</script>
```

Comment: HI like the getMethod() is actually slash inline.

Comment: I'm not sure why but i did it like this  `  if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){` It should work but it is not.

Comment: version 4.1.3 and this is the message that i get.

Comment: @deprecated
The $upper functionality will be removed and this will revert to its PSR-7 equivalent

Comment: that matches with what I said. the "slash inline" is probably just your IDE recognizing that a version of that method is deprecated. the version that you are not using. so when you actually run it you should be fine. i use vscode and it does the same thing for deprecations. but vscode is also buggy so I would not be surprised if it applied a blanket rule without considering that the method has different signatures/versions.

Comment: So it does work oooh I see. So my problem is actually the submit button. But by the way, can I ask about the database I'm having problems with the database I got this error 'Call to a member function getRow() on bool ' how do I actually fix this.

Comment: Which I also explained based on my assumption that you simply did not add a click event listener.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that a careless mistake there but thank you for helping me.

Comment: for your database problem, probably best to ask a different question and include as much information as you can about that issue. I would need to know more about what you are doing, with what and how. What database, what is the code that you are using and try to add more output from your execution.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you could also accept it. I think... I am new here.

Answer (score 3):

vscode also notified me the same, and then I added the line below before the controller class and it works fine.

```
/**
 * @property IncomingRequest $request 
 */
class ContactController extends Controller{
   public function contact(){
   }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I am using CI4 and having the same issue, but the below solution working fine for me

```
if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){}
```

change to this

```
if ($this->request->getPost()) {}

if ($this->request->getGet()) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    //..
}

if($this->request->is('get')){
    //..
}
```